# “Quels” vs “quelles”

Tags: orthographe, accord

Which sentence is correct:

> quelles sont les erreurs ....

or:

> quels sont les erreurs ....

I think that the first one is correct because  **erreurs**, is a plural, female noun. But I have some doubts when I see some sentences on the internet using the 2 examples:
[image]

So I wonder if I miss something, or if there are some exceptions to the rule that I mentioned earlier (if it is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to know rule, that is that the interrogative adjective ***quel* agrees in gender and number with the noun it modifies**.

***Quelles*** sont les **erreurs** à ne pas commettre. (fem. plu.)

***Quels*** sont les différents **types** d'erreurs à ne pas commettre. (mas. plur)

Apart from the fact that we can find lots of incorrect sentences on the Internet (and this in all languages) it seems your images show a mere google search and you have not followed the actual links.*

If you follow the link of the first one "<strike>*quels sont les erreurs à ne pas commettre*</strike>" you can see there are in fact no hits [on the page](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/quels+sont+les+erreurs+%C3%A0+ne+pas+commettre.html) because the words appear separately on *linguee*.

The second image has a correct sentence, *types* being masculine and plural.

*<sub>I have actually found [one result](http://breheretsvt.sytes.net/index.php?article68/quels-sont-les-erreurs-a-ne-pas-commettre-quels-sont-les-impacts-a-prevoir) (not the one you chose!) with <strike>quels sont les erreurs</strike> on the Internet. It **is** a mistake and unless we are sure we are on a trustworthy website everything we read on the internet has to be doublechecked.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You're right in your thought. It should be *quelles* not *quels* because *erreur* is a feminine word.
It would appear to me that the first item in your screenshot is incorrect.

In fact, opening [that link](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=quels+sont+les+erreurs+%C3%A0+ne+pas+commettre&cw=336) shows the correct form (i.e. *quelles*). This leads me to believe that there might have been an indexing error somewhere in the process.

[image: Screenshot of limguee page]